# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT ao Executar Projeto pelo Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com este erro ao executar meu projeto. Já procurei este erro em outros sites e não encontrei respostas.

> Não é possível acessar esse site
>
> localhost demorou muito para responder. Pesquise localhost 4294 Shared
>   Layout no Google ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Está usando o Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Esta usando o IIS express? Veja se a porta não foi alterada.
Tentou limpar e recompilar o projeto?
Qual informação aparece na aba "Saida" do projeto ?